# Pandas: how to choose rows of data with a condition (DataFrameGroupBy)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame monthly_data which look something like this:

```
    DATE_dh TAVG    temp_Celsius
0   195201  29.478261   -1.400966
1   195202  24.800000   -4.000000
2   195203  13.807692   -10.106838
3   195204  39.607143   4.226190
4   195205  44.666667   7.037037
5   195206  56.500000   13.611111
6   195207  61.214286   16.230159
7   195208  57.483871   14.157706
8   195209  47.230769   8.461538
...
334 197911  34.500000   1.388889
335 197912  25.129032   -3.817204
```

I am trying to calculate the mean temperature of each month during these years, so I would eventually end up with 12 rows of data (january, february etc mean temperature). The calculating part is clear to me, but I have no idea how to choose from this dataframe only 195201, 195301, 195401 up to 198001.

I used DataFrameGroupBy to make the DATE_dh so that I now have monthly data instead of daily which was the original.

```
    # Specify the time of the first month (as text)
time1 = '195201'

# Select the group
group1 = grouped.get_group(time1)

# Create an empty DataFrame for the aggregated values
monthly_data = pd.DataFrame()

# The columns that we want to aggregate
mean_cols = ['TAVG']

# Iterate over the groups
for key, group in grouped:
   # Aggregate the data
   mean_values = group[mean_cols].mean()

   # Add the ´key´ (i.e. the date information) into the aggregated values
   mean_values['DATE_dh'] = key

   # Append the aggregated values into the DataFrame
   monthly_data = monthly_data.append(mean_values, ignore_index=True)
```

I probably should continue this way but what is the key now since the data I want to choose isn't anymore multiple 195201 but 195201, 195301...

Answer (score 0):

You can using this as group key

```
df['groupkey']=df.DATE_dh.astype(str).str[-2:]
#df.DATE_dh.astype(str).str[-2:]
Out[216]: 
0    01
1    02
2    03
3    04
4    05
5    06
6    07
7    08
8    09
Name: DATE_dh, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all your time data is in the same format , you could create a new column with the month and then perform a group_by on this column. Let's assume the name of your dataframe is df and the column where your temperature is temp
I would do :

```
df.month = df.Date_dh.apply(lambda x: x[-2:])
#Adds a new column to your dataframe by taking the last 2 characters of the date(the month)
mean_monthly = df[['temp','month']].group_by('month').mean()
#Groups by month value and calculate mean.
```

I think this should do the trick, but feel free to ask if you need clarification.